# What is wrong with this vba code?

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

This code was working fine a few hours ago,I made a few changes and it stopped working. I backtracked all my changes and arrived at where I started - The piece of code that I got off the internet which worked fine before. This is the code

```
   Dim oCn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim oRS As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim ConnString As String
   Dim SQL As String
   Dim qt As QueryTable
   ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Book1.xlsx';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
   Set oCn = New ADODB.Connection
   oCn.ConnectionString = ConnString
   oCn.Open
   SQL = "Select * from [Sheet1$]"
   Set oRS = New ADODB.Recordset
   oRS.Source = SQL
   oRS.ActiveConnection = oCn
   oRS.Open
   Set qt = Worksheets(1).QueryTables.Add(Connection:=oRS, _
   Destination:=Range("A2"))
   oRS.Close
   Set oRS = Nothing
   Set oCn = Nothing
```

When I run it I don't get any errors, the output just fails to appear at the destination. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what and where is 'bracketed'?

Comment: I can't see why you use a querytable rather than copyfromrecordset but you ought to specify the sheet for the destination too: `Set qt = Worksheets(1).QueryTables.Add(Connection:=oRS, _
   Destination:=Worksheets(1).Range("A2"))`

Comment: Put some error handling in, just to see where the code is falling over as a starting point.

Comment: @josieP The actual code has a Where clause in the SQL query and query table give me only one record and ignore others which match the where condition.. so laziness. Specifying sheet name with range does not work

Comment: @SkipIntro The code is not failing anywhere, the output just magically disappears. Maybe it has something to do with ActiveX reference? I am clueless.

Comment: not seeing the laziness-a copyfromrecordset is simpler!

Comment: This code works if you substitute `Worksheets(1).range("a1").copyfromrecordset oRS" instead of your `querytable` line, as you might expect. Bizarre.

Comment: @SkipIntro Yeah I know, I already completed the macro using copyfromrecordset. I just wanted to know why this doesn't work. I swear it was working before.